# When may we interchange the order of differentiation and integration?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, I know of a simple sufficient condition for $$\frac{d}{dy}\int_a^bf(x,y)dx=\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)dx$$ to hold, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ being uniformly continuous (on the rectangle in $\mathbb R^2$ of interest), c.f. Theorem 9.42 of Rudin's *Principle of Mathematical Analysis.*

**Question 1:**  However, if $x$ isn't a scalar, but a real vector, i.e. $x\in \mathbb R^k, f:\mathbb R^{k+1}\to \mathbb R$ and the Riemann integral is replaced by the Lebesgue integral, is there  a simple sufficient condition for interchanging the order of differentiation and integration, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dy}\int_Ef(x,y)d\mu=\int_E\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)d\mu,$$ where the integration is with respect to $x$ on $E\subset \mathbb R^k$?

**Question 2:**  Is $g(x,y)\triangleq \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ being uniformly continuous (on the domain of $f$ in $\mathbb R^{k+1}$) still a sufficient condition?  It appears so to me, if $g(x,y)$ is also Lebesgue integrable on $E$, as justified below:

For $t\ne y$, we have
$$\frac{\int_Ef(x,t)d\mu-\int_Ef(x,y)d\mu}{t-y}= \int_E\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,y)}{t-y}d\mu.$$
Let $g(x,y)\triangleq \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y).$  Then $\frac{f(x,t)-f(x,y)}{t-y}=g(x,s)$ for some $s$ between $t$ and $y$ (mean value theorem).  Since $g(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there certainly exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\mid g(x,u)-g(x,y)\mid < \epsilon$ for any $x$ whenever $|u-y|<\delta.$  Hence, we can construct a sequence of functions, $\psi(x,t)\triangleq \frac{f(x,t)-f(x,y)}{t-y}$ that converges to $g(x,y)$ and is bounded by $|g(x,y)|+\epsilon$, by choosing a sequence of $t$ from $(y-\delta, y+\delta)$.  In fact, every sequence so constructed is bounded by $|g(x,y)|+\epsilon$.  Since $g(x,y)$ is Lebesgue integrable, so is $|g(x,y)|$ and $|g(x,y)|+\epsilon$.  Therefore,

$$\frac{d}{dy}\int_Ef(x,y)d\mu=\lim_{t\to y}\frac{\int_Ef(x,t)d\mu-\int_Ef(x,y)d\mu}{t-y}=\lim_{t\to y}\int_E\psi(x,t)d\mu=\int_Eg(x,y)d\mu,$$

where the last equality follows from Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Am I mistaken somewhere?  Is there a stronger condition that still allows the interchanging of differentiation and integration?  Thanks a lot!